# It's bounty time - suggestions please!

Tags: discussion, bounties

I have a lot of unicorn points (aka reputation), and they're just sitting there doing nothing. I've come to the conclusion the best use of these points is to find questions that need answering, that need a better answer, that need updated answers for Drupal 8, and so on, and exemplary answers that are perhaps buried amongst others, and start/award bounties on them.

There are plenty of these posts around, but I could use some help finding them (plus these points really belong to the community and we should all get a say in how they're spent).

So, please answer this with links to questions you feel are worthy of some extra attention, **one per answer** if you wouldn't mind (that'll make it easier to vote). Suggesting your own posts is absolutely fine, just remember the goal is to get answers to questions that will benefit the greater community.

Hopefully we can discuss briefly how important each is, and how many points to award, and get some great new content on the site!

Comment: Only have time for a quick comment, but I think a quick look through the [tagged:8] questions w/o answers would be good.

Comment: Another suggestion for finding bounty-worthy posts for the community is to look at the [high-voted, no-answer posts](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers).

Comment: [Drush does not work after I sudo su to another user](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194799/drush-does-not-work-after-i-sudo-su-to-another-user)

Comment: It would also be better if the question is not suggested from the user who asked it.

Answer (score 5):

[What is the difference between the Workbench and Workflow modules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/29550/39617)

Besides being minimal, the answers are very old. The modules are really for different use cases, but that isn't made clear. Also, Workflow is actually being more maintained now...its not the clunky thing it used to be IMO.

I think having a more canonical answer would be great for Site Builders looking at which they need for their requirements.

Comment: Yep definitely agree with that, done

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking for a way to solve a problem with Drupal aliases translations when query parameters are passed through clean urls:

[How to avoid Drupal redirecting my multilingual Views pages?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198483)

Comment: That looks like it could be a fairly common (not to mention annoying) problem, fair game for a bounty I think

Comment: Thanks for asking, and the bounty! [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) can be challenging sometimes, especially if combined with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). But: should get (a bit) easier in D8!

Answer (score 3):

I am looking for answers regrading solutions or ways to effectively migrate a drupal 6 site with views to drupal 8.

[Migrating Views from drupal 6 to drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199245/migrating-views)

Answer (score 2):

[How to theme a link in twig/D8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198507/how-to-theme-a-link-in-twig-d8)

Two answers, and there are more possibilities in preprocess, a custom link template or a field formatter. But what is the best thing to do to theme a link?

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[How load only some node fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199268/how-load-only-some-node-fields)

Nodes are complex objects that carry a lot of additional data. Loading this data is inefficient for large sets of nodes. I'm looking for a D8 solution to load data only for specific fields to save processing time and memory but still do this on the API level instead of going into manual database queries.

Comment: Yep agree with that one too, done

Answer (score 2):

[Programmatical use of Search API](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107345/programmatical-use-of-search-api)

Apparently this is a popular question that nobody has guidance on besides the generic answer 'look at module code and figure it out'.

Answer (score 1):

This question is still "open" for additional answers, so I take the risk to post an extra answer ...

If the question is still valid (still applies), you may want to have a look at [Recommendations for security testing a Drupal site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99573/recommendations-for-security-testing-a-drupal-site) ... Would be nice if anybody could come up with a D8 update of it ("I" won't, but I'd be interested in such update from whoever).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another candidate to consider: [Latest Best Practise: Reusing content/functionality between Drupal 7 sites](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/latest-best-practise-reusing-content-functionality-between-drupal-7-sites)

Apart from the obvious (using "CMI" and/or "Features"): how should the existing answer be "upgraded" to a D8-equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one to consider: [Including a different jQuery version only on specific page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54014/how-to-include-a-different-jquery-version-only-on-specific-page)

It has an answer for D6, and D7, but not for D8 ...

Answer (score 0):

[Inside Panelizer, is there a trick to formatting image fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199704/inside-panelizer-is-there-a-trick-to-formatting-images)

Answer (score 0):

[Spaces module aware panels page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196031/spaces-module-aware-panels-page)

Answer (score 0):

[How to quickly configure allowed content for panelizer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199418/how-to-quickly-configure-allowed-content-for-panelizer)